# xmpp ssl cipher negotiation

Tags: tls, protocols, instant-messaging, xmpp

Does anyone know how ssl ciphers are nogitiated via the xmpp protocol. When I capture packets, I see:

```
<starttls xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-tls'/>
```

There is no hello server/client or cipher negotiation, like http. Can anyone point to somewhere I can get more information

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As explained in [RFC 3920](http://xmpp.org/rfcs/rfc3920.html#tls) (section 5), a machine will send the "`<starttls>`" tag to indicate that it supports SSL/TLS, and then, when the final "`>`" of a subsequent "`<proceed/>`" XML element is sent and received, the underlying connection is immediately hijacked to begin a [TLS handshake](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#section-7.3). The handshake consists in TLS messages (which are not XML at all), beginning with `ClientHello` (from the TLS "client") and then `ServerHello` (from the TLS "server") which includes cipher suite negotiation.

There is no method in XMPP to advertise specific TLS cipher suite support before the TLS handshake. From a packet capture view, you will see the `ClientHello` and `ServerHello` right after the "`<proceed/>`" tag, not where the "`<starttls>`" element occurs.

A consequence is that machines who use XMPP to talk to each other cannot know whether they will be able to find a TLS cipher suite that they both support before actually committing to TLS usage. It is not a big issue in practice, because SSL/TLS implementations support some fallback cipher suites which all implementations know of (RSA+RC4+SHA-1 and RSA+3DES+SHA-1, namely), even if they usually *prefer* some other cipher suites.

Comment: Small note, the latest XMPP specification is RFC6120.

Comment: Also, regarding the concern about not having a common cipher, RFC 6120 makes implementation of at least TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA mandatory: http://xmpp.org/rfcs/rfc6120.html#security-mti-conf